# How do I get the commit date and the merge date when looking at the commit history of a file in Github?

Tags: github

i.e. on [this page](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb)

Do the dates refer to when the commit was made? or when it was merged in? And how can I find out the other?

Thank you,

edit: Ideally I don't have to clone the repo down and use the git CLI.

edit2: It looks like the dates in that link are the dates from when the commit was made. So how does one find out when the commit was merged into the branch using Github's GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at an history involving merges (like [the one for the git repo itself](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master)), you would see:

- the merge commit
- followed by the two parent commits (which have been merged)

So in case of a merge, you would still be able to see "when the commit was merged into the branch"

[image: merge on GitHub]